# ErrorException Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: /home/rimonet2/boostbuy.ng/resources/views/admin/pages/dashboard.blade.php)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, error-handling, laravel-blade

When I log in to my admin dashboard, it brings up this error exception.

And pointed out this specific line of code as the issue:

[image: Error in code at line 363]

Comment: `service` looks like a relation, and if it is, the reference is not an object, more likely null or something else not an object?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because of the line #363. You're trying to render `$sale->service->id` when the value of `$sale->service` is null, so null has no properties inside.

**How to solve:**

Render it with null-safe operators (works if you're using php 8.0 or above):

```
{{ $sale->service?->id }}
```

But I think it is not as good as to render some error for user instead of empty string:

```
@if ($sale->service) {{ $sale->service->id }} @else without service @endif
```

*P.S. if any sale has a service by your business logic then you should check a method where you're creating the Sale object. Make sure that the service_id field is set.*